# How to show different navigation bar on before login and after login page using angular js 1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have two different navigation bar files. If user not logged in then he should show before_login_navigation.html and if a user is logged in then he should show after_login_navigation.html. How do I achieve it?
I am using Angular JS.

I am using below code for showing .html files,

```
<div ng-if="loggedIn == false"> 
    <div ng-include src="'partials/before_login_navigation.html'"> </div>
</div>

<div ng-if="loggedIn == true">
    <div ng-include src="'partials/aftter_login_navigation.html'"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post your code, explain how you handle the login, show how you include your navigation HTML...

Comment: What is the error. Where is the controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Do the partials that you are using having different controllers....??`

```
<div ng-if="loggedIn == false"> 
<div ng-include src="'partials/before_login_navigation.html'" ng-controller="your_controller"> </div>
```

OR

Use one ng-include file and then write ng-if condition inside it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-show`

```
<div ng-show="!loggedIn"> 
    <div ng-include src="'partials/before_login_navigation.html'"> </div>
</div>

<div ng-show="loggedIn">
    <div ng-include src="'partials/aftter_login_navigation.html'"> </div>
</div>
```

This is assuming that the `loggedIn` variable has already been declared (in your controller/app) and will be set to false by default and true when the user logs in successfully and back to false when the user logs out or the user is logged out